# How To install python 32 bit on Red Hat Linux 64 bit

Tags: python

I have installed python2.7 64 bit on linux red hat  and trying to add python module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycleartool/2007.01 , but it looks that package only works on 32 bit, 
so  my question is how to install python 32 bit on 64 bit Red Hat Linux or how to install python package pycleartool on python2.7 64 bit  ???

Answer (score 0):

For installing 32 bit python

First, install `ia32-libs` which is required to install any 32 bit application on Linux.

[Download python](http://python.org/download/)

Extract the file and `cd` to the directory.

configure using the command `OPT=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --prefix=/opt/pym32`

run `make`